# Audio not working in Ubuntu 20.04 after switching over from dual-booted OS (Solution)

Tags: dual-boot, sound, suspend

Are you having audio issues after switching to Ubuntu from another OS (like windows) on a dual-booted device? Is everything showing as normal, but you just can't hear anything? **Don't worry, it's an easy fix.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify any config files or anything. Just put your PC to sleep by either manually putting it to sleep or just closing it if its a laptop. Wait for about 20 seconds and then open it/start it up again. It should work now. Don't restart it or anything. I had this issue and this worked just fine for me. I hope I could help